# c++ read input until the end of line char array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my code work, actually it works but not that well. The code stops after 'enter' appeared. I want to make my code work until the end of file input from user.

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char input[2000];


    cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));

    int lol = strlen(input);
    int boing = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < lol; p++)
    {

        if (input[p] == '\"')
        {
            boing++;
            if (boing % 2 == 1)
            {
                cout << '\`'<<'\`';
            }
            if (boing % 2 == 0)
            {
                cout << '\''<<'\'';
            }
        }
        else
            cout << input[p];
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

if we enter input these words

> Is branched in ""my up strictly "remember. "
>   Songs but chief has ham widow downs. Genius or so up vanity cannot. 
>   '''```Large do tried `goi"'`''ng" about water defer by. "Silent" son man she wished mother. 
>   Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance additions to. 
>   We """"diminution preference "thoroughly if. "Joy deal pain ';`392view" much her time. Led young gay would now state."

my output become

> Is branched in `''my up strictly`remember. ''

but it should be

> Is branched in `''my up strictly`remember. '' Songs but chief has
>   ham widow downs. Genius or so up vanity cannot.  '''```Large do tried
>   `goi`'`''ng'' about water defer by.`Silent'' son man she wished
>   mother.  Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance
>   additions to.  We `''`''diminution preference `` thoroughly if. ''Joy
>   deal pain ';`392view `` much her time. Led young gay would now state.''

Comment: You are not doing yourself a favor by giving variables "funny" names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**for this code you you need to two more header file**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**your full code will be**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char input[2000];


    cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));

    int lol = strlen(input);
    int boing = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < lol; p++)
    {

        if (input[p] == '\"')
       {
           boing++;
           if (boing % 2 == 1)
           {
               cout << '\`'<<'\`';
           }
           if (boing % 2 == 0)
           {
              cout << '\''<<'\'';
           }
      }
      else
        cout << input[p];
   }

   cout<<endl;   //this line is for making ur code look nice

   system("pause");
}
```

**but i personally suggest you to use c++ string class for string handling**
**it easy and very useful**

**using string class your code will be**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   string input;

   getline(cin,input);

   int lol = input.size();

   int boing = 0;
   for (int p = 0; p < lol; p++)
   {

      if (input[p] == '\"')
      {
          boing++;
          if (boing % 2 == 1)
          {
             cout << '\`'<<'\`';
          }
          if (boing % 2 == 0)
          {
              cout << '\''<<'\'';
          }
      }
      else
          cout << input[p];
   }

   cout<<endl;
   system("pause");

   return 0;

}
```

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 5):

`getline` will take input until the "enter" button is pressed. 
Your code runs fine on my machine.
Just add `string.h` header file like this:

`#include<string.h>`

This is for the `strlen` function.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your `getline` in some form of loop.  Right now you are getting 1 line, then manipulating `input` then exiting.  Right now you are pulling it in from the user so you need to look for a terminator.